# Updating column data using a variable

Tags: python, mysql

I have been trying to update my column data using a variable. Am I using the correct syntax?

I've tried looking for syntaxes but I still get the same error.

```
p1Score = 1
mycursor.execute("UPDATE test SET score = %s WHERE players = 'Player one'")
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
```

I expect the score column of p1 to change into 1 but I get an error that says mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s WHERE players = 'Player One'' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the value of %s.
The correct query is

```
p1Score = (1)
mycursor.execute("UPDATE test SET score = %s WHERE players = 'Player one'",p1Score )
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
```